# Are there other surgeries with comparable restrictions to the real-life test for transsexual genital surgery?

Tags: surgery

Transsexuals seeking [sex reassignment surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_reassignment_surgery) require at least one, and usually two, referrals from medical professionals.  Ordinarily, in order to get these referrals the patient must have completed one year of [real-life experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-life_experience_%28transgender%29) (the "real-life test"), where they live consistently as their stipulated gender.

> *Question*: Are there other surgeries with comparable restrictions to the real-life test for transsexual genital surgery?

I'm not aware of any.  I know there can be long waiting lists for surgery, but that's different to waiting to be put on a waiting list for surgery.

I've heard in some places to obtain an abortion you need to wait a few days.  That's the closest I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [six month rule](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4394109/) demanding abstinence from alcohol for liver transplants.  I can't immediately find evidence of similar rules for other organs, but they might exist.

There can also be a [cooling-off period](http://baaps.org.uk/baapsmedia/docs/code_of_conduct.pdf) for plastic surgery, but that's not really a lifestyle test.  It's kind of the opposite.

Comment: That first one is exactly what I'm after.  Thank you!

Comment: If you ever watch the show "600 lb life" the surgeon always asks the patients to lose a significant amount of weight (eg 30 or 50 lbs) before the bariatric surgery, to demonstrate that they can change their activity level and what they are eating. I don't know if that is particular to that one surgeon or a general practice.